# Printing column value in the next line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

My input is in TSV format:

```
C1
   r1
   r2
   r3
C2
   r1
   r3
```

Desired output is:

```
C1 r1
   r2
   r3
C2 r1
   r3
```

So, basically what I want is printing value of column 1 in next line, is it possible using Linux command?

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -i.bak '/^[^[:blank:]]/{N;s/\n[[:blank:]]\+//;}' file
C1r1
  r2
  r3
C2r1
  r3
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is with `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /C/ { p = 1; save = $1; } $1 !~ /C/ { if (p) { x = save $1; print x; p = 0; } else { print $0; } }' input
```

Result:

```
C1r1
  r2
  r3
C2r1
  r3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ed`:

```
$ ed -s input <<EOT
g/^C/+ s/^[[:space:]]*//
g/^C/  j                
w output
EOT
```